# Access shared network files from Windows Phone 8 app?

Tags: networking, windows-phone-8, shared

I am looking for a way to access shared network files from Windows Phone 8 app. I have found one application which can do so.I believe using sockets is one way but I have never done socket programming before. Can anyone suggest me on how to start?